# react filter eslint error: unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to filter an array in react. Here's my code:

```
resultArray = myArray.filter((item) => {
  return item.children.length === 0;
});
```

This gives me an eslint error:
`Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body`

So I traded the braces for parentheses:

```
resultArray = myArray.filter((item) => (
  return item.children.length === 0;
));
```

This gives me an unexpected token error while highlighting the `return`.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes as @DanielSchneider already says:

you can use a shorthand (or also called lambda) arrow function as follows:

```
resultArray = myArray.filter(
  item => item.children.length === 0 //this is the lambda function
);
```

because it is a single expression and a return value (even if the return value is undefined) you can use the short hand arrow function. It will always return the result of the expression (even undefined).

Comment: accepting this one as answer because the other still gave me an eslint error. Possibly because of my linting configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Because is a single expression, you can do the following:

```
resultArray = myArray.filter((item) => item.children.length === 0);
```